# How to tell Fluent NHibernate not to map a class property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a class that is mapped in fluent nhibernate but I want one of the classes properties to be ignored by the mapping.

With class and mapping below I get this error:

***The following types may not be used as proxies:
iMasterengine.Data.Model.Calendar: method get_HasEvents should be virtual***

```
//my class
public class Calendar : IEntity {
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string SiteId { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<CalendarEvent> Events { get; set; }
    //ignore this property
    public bool HasEvents { get { return Events.Count > 0; } }
}

//my mapping
public class CalendarMap : ClassMap<Calendar> {
    public CalendarMap() {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.SiteId);
        HasMany(x => x.Events).Inverse();
        //what do I put here to tell nhibernate
        //to ignore my HasEvents property?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
map.IgnoreProperty(p => p.What);
```

Comment: Where should that line be placed? I figured it would go into the CalendarMap constructor, but I don't see a map instance available there.

Comment: It should be added where you create the configuration. See this link [http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping#Ignoring_properties](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping#Ignoring_properties)

Comment: IgnoreProperty() is only for *automapping* if you are specifying your mappings yourself (i.e. using classmap) then this is not relevant.  The poster has included a classmap, and has not said anything about automapping, so I don't see what relevance this has.

Comment: I came across this from google, and I am automapping, so even though it may not answer the question, it answered mine

Comment: will i able to change per user basis means,i want to make it available for set of users and hide for some set of users.

Comment: Where do I add this?

Answer (score 29):

You can just make `HasEvents` *virtual* in the class:

```
public virtual bool HasEvents { get { return Events.Count > 0; } }
```

You don't need to add anything to the mappings.

You only need to tell fluent to ingore a property if you are using Auto Mapping, which I don't think you are.

Comment: Doesn't work for me going through Linq on an old version of NHibernat.e

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `[Ignore]` attribute in the `AutoMapper.Configuration.Annotations` namespace. Place it directly above the property declaration.