# Fluent NHibernate (ignore a specific property)

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to tell Fluent NHibernate not to map a class property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907576/how-to-tell-fluent-nhibernate-not-to-map-a-class-property)

How can I ignore the property People from being mapped? **Code will help**.

```
public class Staff :  IStaff 
{
    public virtual DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
    public virtual int StaffID { get; set; }
    public virtual int PersonID { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsATeachingStaff { get; set; }
    //This is the property I want to exclude from mapping
    public virtual  IPeople  People { get; set; }
 }



    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        string ConnectionString = "Data Source=DELL;Initial Catalog=University;Integrated Security=True";
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ShowSql().ConnectionString(ConnectionString))
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<School.Business.lib.FHibernate.Mapper.PeopleMap>().ExportTo(@"c:\log"))
            .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)          
            .BuildSessionFactory();        
    }



public class StaffMap : ClassMap<Staff>
{
    public StaffMap()
    {
        Table("Staff");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.StaffID).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("StaffID");
        Map(x => x.PersonID).Column("PersonID");
        Map(x => x.DateAdded).Not.Nullable().Column("DateAdded");
        Map(x => x.DateUpdated).Not.Nullable().Column("DateUpdated");
        Map(x => x.CreatedBy).Not.Nullable().Column("CreatedBy");
        Map(x => x.ModifiedBy).Not.Nullable().Column("ModifiedBy");
        Map(x => x.IsActive).Column("IsActive");
        Map(x => x.IsDeleted).Column("IsDeleted");
        Map(x => x.IsATeachingStaff).Column("IsATeachingStaff");
    }
}
```