# How to ignore mapping of property using mapping by code "Conventions"

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Is there any way to avoid a property from being mapped with NHibernate 3.2 using mapping by code conventions? By default, all properties are mapped.

Comment: Yes. Don't map it. i.e. don't go Property(x => x.MyProperty) in your ClassMapping code.

Comment: There is currently no easy way of doing it. Please vote for this to make it happen: [NH-2816](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2816)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options as far as I know:

1)Extend ConventionModelMapper and SimpleModelInspector to extend IsPersistentProperty such that it meets your need.

2)Use IsPersistentProperty as follows:

```
...
mapper.IsPersistentProperty((memberInfo, declared) => IsPersistentProperty(mapper.ModelInspector, memberInfo, declared, "YourPropertyName"));
...


public static bool IsPersistentProperty(IModelInspector modelInspector, MemberInfo member, bool declared, string propertyName)
{
    return (declared ||(member is PropertyInfo) && !IsReadOnlyProperty(member)) && !member.Name.Equals(propertyName);
}

private static bool IsReadOnlyProperty(MemberInfo subject)
{
    const BindingFlags defaultBinding = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;

    var property = subject as PropertyInfo;
    if (property == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (CanReadCantWriteInsideType(property) || CanReadCantWriteInBaseType(property))
    {
        return !PropertyToField.DefaultStrategies.Values.Any(s => subject.DeclaringType.GetField(s.GetFieldName(property.Name), defaultBinding) != null) || IsAutoproperty(property);
    }
    return false;
}

private static bool IsAutoproperty(PropertyInfo property)
{
    return property.ReflectedType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance
                                                                             | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).Any(pi => pi.Name == string.Concat("<", property.Name, ">k__BackingField"));
}

private static bool CanReadCantWriteInsideType(PropertyInfo property)
{
    return !property.CanWrite && property.CanRead && property.DeclaringType == property.ReflectedType;
}

private static bool CanReadCantWriteInBaseType(PropertyInfo property)
{
    if (property.DeclaringType == property.ReflectedType)
    {
        return false;
    }
    var rfprop = property.DeclaringType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance
                                                                             | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).SingleOrDefault(pi => pi.Name == property.Name);
    return rfprop != null && !rfprop.CanWrite && rfprop.CanRead;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

2) As alternative to copy&paste of default implementation of IsPersistentProperty it can be reused via reflection:

```
var mapper = new ConventionModelMapper();
var field = mapper.ModelInspector.GetType()
    .GetField( "isPersistentProperty", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance );

var ispp = (Func<MemberInfo, bool, bool>)field.GetValue( mapper.ModelInspector );
mapper.IsPersistentProperty( ( mi, b ) => ispp( mi, b ) 
   && ( /*any conditions here*/ mi.Name != "SomeFiledName" ) );
```

Conditions can be moved to separate method or class. An stronly-typed wrapper based on expressions can be done above it.

Comment: Can you give a sample how to use that?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate: [Ignore column using mapping by code in HNibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658647/ignore-column-using-mapping-by-code-in-hnibernate)

you can use the following:

```
mapper.IsPersistentProperty((mi, declared) =>
                                             {
                                                 if (mi.DeclaringType == typeof (YourType) && mi.Name == "PropertyNameToIgnore")
                                                     return false;
                                                 return true;
                                             });
```

Comment: Can you provide the simplest possible example that will cause any number of properties to be ignored using a BeforeMapProperty handler?

Comment: This is wrong code. It makes EVERY property of every mapped class persistent except "PropertyNameToIgnore" of YourType class. Those are readonly, the once mapped via fields and so on.