# NHibernate: mapping field consisting of the sum of cells

Tags: sql, sql-server, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

SQL:

```
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [MiddleInitial] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Surname] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
```

Mapping:

```
    public string    FirstName { get; set; }
    public string    MiddleInitial { get; set; }
    public string    Surname { get; set; }

    m.Map(x => x.FirstName).Length(255);
    m.Map(x => x.MiddleInitial).Length(255);
    m.Map(x => x.Surname).Length(255);
```

I need to add the Fullname  field consisting of the [FirstName] + " " +[MiddleInitial]+ " " + [Surname]. (For using search in jqGrid)

Pls help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this with FORMULA

```
Map(x => x.Fullname).Formula("select FirstName+ ' ' + Surname + ' ' + MiddleInitial from Customer");
```

*Its needed for ICriteria*

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you seem to be using this just on the front-end: How about a non-persiteable, read-only property?

```
private static string _fullNameFormat = "{0} {1} {2}";
public string FullName
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format(_fullNameFormat,this.FirstName,this.MiddleInitial,this.Surname);
    }
}
```

Untested, but should do it. In case NHibernate insists persisting the property, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907576/how-to-tell-fluent-nhibernate-not-to-map-a-class-property)

The other, least invasive, alternative is to use an extension method for that Model

```
public static class ModelExtensions
{
    private static string _fullNameFormat = "{0} {1} {2}";
    public static string ToFullName(this Person person)
    {
        return string.Format(_fullNameFormat,person.FistName,person.MiddleInitial,person.Surname);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in this case you would compute the attribute in model:

public string Fullname
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}",
            FirstName, MiddleInitial, Surname)
            .Replace("  "," ").Trim();
    }
}