# How do I add additional column to databound class in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql

I've got a class that mimics my data on a Server API.

```cs
public class Table1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In my application, I need to keep track of adding, modifying, and deleting records.

To decide which fields are added and deleted, I modified that class with an **ActionType**:

```cs
public class Table1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ActionType { get; set; }
}
```

That seemed great, but now whenever data is pulled from the Server API:

```cs
var table1 = _db.Table1.Where(x => x.Id == paramId);
foreach (var item in table1)
{
```

The **Where** clause does not fail, but as soon as I attempt to iterate over the results, I get:

> **SQLException:** Invalid column name 'ActionType'.

Is there a way to mark this added parameter as "not part of the database"?

Comment: Tag your question with the ORM library that you're using.

Comment: For NHibernate check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/907576/10601203, and for Entity Framework check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10385248/10601203. If you're not using either, please specify what you are using as Michael said.

Comment: @MichaelLiu - what do you mean by what library? Like Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0):

The key is that this is an unmapped column, hence it requires the `[NotMapped]` attribute:

```cs
public class Table1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int ActionType { get; set; }
}
```

After that, there is no more problem.